# RSpec test not invoking controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I've got a simple test, pretty much what the scaffold generated, although I can't figure out why it's not working.  Here's the situation:

I've got an AttachmentsController:

```
  # POST /attachments
  # POST /attachments.xml
  def create
    @attachment = Attachment.new(params[:attachment])
    @attachment.idea_id = params[:idea_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @attachment.save
        format.html { redirect_to(idea_path(params[:idea_id]), :notice => 'Attachment was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @attachment, :status => :created, :location => @attachment }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @attachment.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end

    end
  end
end
```

And a spec:

```
describe AttachmentsController do
  def mock_attachment(stubs={})
    @mock_attachment ||= mock_model(Attachment, stubs).as_null_object
  end

  describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "assigns a newly created attachment as @attachment" do
        Attachment.stub(:new).with({'these' => 'params'}) { mock_attachment(:save => true) }
        post :create,:attachment => {'these' => 'params'}
        assigns(:attachment).should be(mock_attachment)
      end
```

but this (and every other test in this spec) fails with something along the lines of

```
expected #<Attachment:33902000> => #<Attachment:0x2054db0 @name="Attachment_1001">
     got #<NilClass:4> => nil
```

Because, for reasons I can't figure out, AttachmentsController#create isn't being called.

The route is there:

```
POST   /attachments(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"attachments"}
```

This is what the log says:

```
  Processing by AttachmentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"attachment"=>{"these"=>"params"}}
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 302 Found in 52ms (Views: 23.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I should also note that I can invoke the create code (and it works great) through the website itself.. it's just the tests that are failing.

So what would cause post() or get() not to invoke the controller like this??

Comment: I'm not very familiar with RSpec however it seems to me that `mock_attachment` is nil could you replace it with sth else like `:true` and run your test?

Comment: Can you post the full create action code?

Comment: Dude youre missing the create code. Thats the key to your question.

Comment: I added the full body of the create code.   However, I didn't think it was relevant, as the create code is never called (as evidenced by breakpoints, logging, etc) thus :attachment remains Nil.

Comment: Are there any `before_filter` statements that could be preventing the create action from being invoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try should_receive and put it into before block as it's a better practice:

```
describe AttachmentsController do
  describe "POST create" do
    let(:attachment) { mock_attachment(:save => save_result) }

    subject { post :create, :attachment => params }

    before do
      Attachment.should_receive(:new).and_return(attachment)
    end

    describe "with valid params" do
      let(:attachment_params) { {'these' => 'params'} }
      let(:save_result) { true }

      it "assigns a newly created attachment as @attachment" do
        assigns(:attachment).should be(mock_attachment)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however even with this approach I still have the same problem -- the call to post:create never invokes AttachemntController#create

Comment: Ah, I just looked at the logs...it ends up with a redirect - maybe you have to be logged in to be able to use this action? Or there's some other before filter that does a redirect?

Comment: I had exactly the same problem... in my case Cancan was preventing my test user to access that action. I figure this out by tailing the test.log when running my tests. Remember that: "Logs are your friend, so pay them a visit every now and then"

Answer (score 10):

For future viewers of this question, the actual answer was posted by @solnic in a comment to the accepted answer: **check your logs**. In this case (and in my own situation) a redirect caused this problem, which was only visible in the logs.